# Using xpath to extract a list of values

Tags: xpath

Is there a way that I can extract data so it will be output as follows?

```
Color, Cognac, Shoe Size, 12, 10994
Color, Cognac, Shoe Size, 13, 10995
```

The values inside any tags can be dynamic, so selectors must use tag names.
There will be a dynamic number of `SKU`s.

I'm able to extract individual values e.g

```
//SKUs/Attributes/name/text() .. Color
//SKUs/Attributes/Values/values/text() .. Cognac
```

But the dynamic nature of the number of `SKUs+Attributes` is challenging.

`XML` ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root> 
  <SKUs> 
    <Attributes>   
      <Values> 
        <values>Cognac</values>  
      </Values>  
      <name>Color</name>  
    </Attributes>  
    <Attributes> 
      <Values> 
        <values>12</values>  
      </Values>  
      <name>Shoe Size</name>  
    </Attributes>  
    <SKUUniqueID>10994</SKUUniqueID> 
  </SKUs>  
  <SKUs> 
    <Attributes> 
      <Values> 
        <values>Cognac</values>  
      </Values>  
      <name>Color</name>  
    </Attributes>  
    <Attributes> 
      <Values> 
        <values>13</values>  
      </Values>  
      <name>Shoe Size</name>  
    </Attributes>  
    <SKUUniqueID>10995</SKUUniqueID> 
  </SKUs> 
</root>
```

Comment: You didn't even mention what language you're working in.

Comment: It'd be easy to provide a self-contained answer to this using XQuery. XPath, however, isn't powerful enough to do this in one step -- meaning we need to be able to run multiple XPath queries, meaning we need to know your implementation language.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy , didn't realize `XPath` couldn't do this itself without intervention of the implementation language. I'm working in `Java`

Comment: Would you mind a non-Java answer (demonstrating techniques which would be entirely usable in a Java implementation)? Some of the practices used by the currently accepted answer are rather unfortunate, but Java is something I generally write only under duress. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do using java.

you need to count the SKU's first and iterate on them

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XPathExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /*
         * disclaimer - code from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/
         */
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(
                "//path//to//sample.xml"));
        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        NodeList skus = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//SKUs").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i=1;i<skus.getLength()+1;i++) {
            String t1 = xPath.compile("//SKUs["+i+"]/Attributes[1]/name[1]").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            String t2 = xPath.compile("//SKUs["+i+"]/Attributes[1]/Values/identifier[1]").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            String t3 = xPath.compile("//SKUs["+i+"]/Attributes[2]/name[1]").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            String t4 = xPath.compile("//SKUs["+i+"]/Attributes[2]/Values/identifier[1]").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            String id = xPath.compile("//SKUs["+i+"]/SKUUniqueID").evaluate(xmlDocument);
            System.out.println(t1+","+t2+","+t3+","+t4+","+id);
        }
    }
}
```

also notice that it's not clear in your xml where the values come from because they may come from different places.

Comment: This would me more efficient on large unindexed documents if you found the `SKUs` item first, and ran the rest of your queries relative to that element not relevant to the root. Worse, using string concatenation to build the query rather than bind variables opens you up to the XPath equivalent of SQL injection.

Comment: ...which is to say -- if you're Doing It Right, you can search for `SKUs[$i]`, and pass in `i` out-of-band.

Comment: Also, this means you **don't** need to count the SKUs first, but can have your first query return the set of SKUs elements, and your other queries run directly from that returned element rather than from the document root.

Comment: well, to be honest the problems i see with my solution are [1] loading the whole xml as a dom instead of using a sax parser is not a good idea for huge xmls and [2] i've tried to iterate on skus nodelist and apply the xpath to the subgraph as you suggest but i could not make it work, so I was kind of lazy and just posted what worked for me (I don't even know if who posted the question will use java anyway). But the good thing about SO is that anyone can just spend more time than me to post a better solution for this problem :-)

Comment: *nod*; indeed. I might try my own hand if the OP indicates they'll accept a non-Java solution; could whip something out in a few lines of Python or Clojure, but Java gives me hives.